# Is two-way binding needed to share data between components needed for this?

Tags: angular

I am having some troubles figuring out how to get data to update in a child component when new data is added from the parent component.

I have a template that looks something like this:

```
<ion-content>

  <app-feed-comments [comments]="comments" [userId]="userId" (newCommentsEvent)="newComments($event)"></app-feed-comments>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-textarea #commentarea [(ngModel)]="comment" (ionInput)="textinput($event)" placeholder="Write a comment..." rows="1"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button color="medium" (click)="addComment()" [disabled]="comment.length < 5">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="send"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I am passing my `comments` to the child component, but when I add a new comment from the `addComment` method, it is not pushing the new comment to the child component.

I am using an `EventEmitter` to output new comments to the parent component, in an infinite scroll capacity.

This is my `addComment` method in my `feed.ts` file:

```
addComment() {

    let commentData = {
      feedID: this.feedId,
      comment: this.comment
    };
    this.api.post('feed/comment', commentData).subscribe((response:any) => {
      if (!response.status.error) {
        this.newComments(response.data.comment);
        this.comment = '';
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.content.scrollToBottom();
        });
      }
    });
  }

newComments(comments:any) {
    this.comments.push(...comments);
  }
```

Any thoughts on the best way to achieve this? Am I going at it the wrong way, or have I just overlooked something?

Answer (score 0):

You don't (necessarily) need an `EventEmitter` in the parent but rather the child component must listen for the changes of its input.

This can be achieved by implementing the `OnChanges` interface and `ngOnChanges` method in the child component.

This is sometimes not necessary if the child component make a "direct" use of the`@Input` variable but if you need to do something when the input changes, `ngOnChanges` is the method to implement.